# Python Telethon get all admins of group

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I want to get admins of Telegram groups, I try with this code but I get empty response, my code

```
client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
result = client(functions.channels.GetParticipantsRequest(
    channel='mychannel',
    filter=types.ChannelParticipantsAdmins(),
    offset=42,
    limit=100,
    hash=0
))
print(result.stringify())
```

this is my response I've got

```
ChannelParticipants(
        count=1,
        participants=[
        ],
        users=[
        ]
)
```

Answer (score 4):

As per the [client reference](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/client-reference.html), you can use [`client.iter_participants`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.iter_participants) to iterate over the participants of a group. Furthermore, you can use the `filter` parameter to narrow down the results. The documentation also includes this example:

```py
# Filter by admins
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsAdmins
async for user in client.iter_participants(chat, filter=ChannelParticipantsAdmins):
    print(user.first_name)
```

Comment: Note that the filter won't work on small group chat. For those, check the type of `user.participant` while iterating.

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is for long time ago, but still maybe someone had same question.
Answer:
your code is correct and return all admins of channel. and it have only 1 admin (showen by 'count=1' in your result).
but you set 'offset' parameter to 42, but it has only 1 admin. so it show empty result.
if your channel had let say 50 admins (indexing 0-49), by setting 'offset' to 42 it shows you from index 42 to 49.

Answer (score -1):

Try passing the value 1 to the offset argument

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.