# How to get admins of a simple chat using Telethon?

Tags: python, client, chat, telegram, telethon

I'm stuck during the work with Telethon. For channels the following works and I can get all admins of a channel:

```
parts = await client(GetParticipantsRequest(
        chat, ChannelParticipantsSearch(''), 0, 1000,
        hash=0
    ))
for i in parts.participants:
    if type(i) in [ChannelParticipantCreator, ChannelParticipantAdmin]:
        print(i)
```

But how to get the same for simple chats (groups/PeerChats)? Because if I execute the code above in such chats then I get the following:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast InputPeerChat to any kind of InputChannel.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/68985748.

Comment: @Lonami The comment of the first answer helped me, thanks!